# Possible to have main effects and interaction in 2-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova, interaction, interpretation

In a 2 way ANOVA, can you have a significant main effect for each IV and an interaction? Why should caution be used when interpreting main effects if you have an interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the interaction exists, it is difficult to define the main effect.

Here is makeup-ed extreme case: Suppose drug A and B can change the blood pressure, but they effect (change of blood pressure in mmHg) are different for different gender. The effects are as following:

```
                 ---------------------------------------
                              male           female
                          ------------------------------
                   Drug A       10              -10 
                   Drug B      -10               10
                 ---------------------------------------
```

Under this situation, I cannot find a way to define the main effect of drug and gender on blood pressure.